# Having issue with a HP LaserJet 3030 (All-in-One) printer

Tags: usb, printing, hp, pdf, laserjet

I'm struggling to get my ancient HP LaserJet 3030 (All-In-One) printer to play nicely with my HP Elitebook Folio 9470m laptop.

I'm able to print with no issues on a Win10 laptop (Dell Inspiron 15R 7520 SE).

Issue: Cannot print beyond first page of any PDF file that contains images.

Aim: To use my laptop as a printer server, so I don't need to move my Win10 laptop around, and I can print from my Samsung Galaxy S9 phone on demand.

Troubleshooting steps:

- Connected printer via USB cable, foolishly expecting it to work. It showed up in settings :)
- Attempted to print the intended PDF file. Printer flashed green light on power LED, and printed the first page. Nothing else was printed.

Steps taken in attempt to resolve:

- Checked that this printer is supported by Ubuntu (it is, see: https://developers.hp.com/hp-laserjet-3030-all-one-printer)
- https://www.openprinting.org/printer/HP/HP-LaserJet_3030 -> Recommended I download hplip as a driver.
- Downloaded hplip (v3.22.10) from HP's site  and attempted to run hp-setup in gui mode.
- I completed the first step (actually step 11 of the installation instructions) of connecting the USB cable to the left-hand side USB port, but it could not detect my printer. (that port does work, as I can see my Samsung Galaxy S9 show up as a USB storage).
- Switched to right, front (I mean the USB port that closest to you, if you were sitting in front of the laptop), and the printer was detected. Both the name and local URI was shown.
- However, upon clicking the "Next" button, it kept saying that hp-setup was unresponsive. Gave it around 1min to fix it self, tried again, no dice.
- In Ubuntu settings, the "Printers" section shows a constantly spinning large loading icon. I attempted to fix it by resetting the config file. I ran "dconf reset -f /org/gnome/", and restarted my machine. No change.

Result: User is very annoyed at HP.

Background details:

- HP Laptop: running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (currently in process of
  upgrading to 22.10).
- Hp-lip version (at time of post): 3.22.10

Comment: if the aim is to only print from your Samsung S9 mobile device, why not install Samsung Print Service Plugin on it? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sec.app.samsungprintservice&gl=US

Comment: This printer doesn't support Wifi/Wifi Direct, and can only use USB 2.0 to be connected.

I was able to print one page of the same PDF via CUPS, but I'm too inexperienced to know what to change/edit in the config files.

What I'm essentially doing is trying connecting up an older laptop to an even older printer to be compatible with modern standards.